# Im trying to read a saved pickled models that are saved in a folder, I'm looping through the folder but I keep getting an error

Tags: python, machine-learning

p="/Users/rama/Desktop/lowermodels"
lowerCount=0
for i in range(19):
lowermodel[i]= pickle.load(open('/Users/rama/Desktop/lowermodels{lowerCount}.sav', 'rb'))
lowerCount= lowerCount+1

[image: this is the error i keep getting, there are 19 different files in the folder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to put an f infront of your f-string

```py
p="/Users/rama/Desktop/lowermodels"
lowerCount=0
for i in range(19):
    lowermodel[i]= pickle.load(open(f'/Users/rama/Desktop/lowermodels{lowerCount}.sav', 'rb'))
    lowerCount= lowerCount+1
```